# Cancel focusout event if focus is over next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a unsorted list under a input element.

If I click outside the ul- or input-element I want to close the ul.

But I dont know how to realize it with jQ.

To detect if the input element lose the focus i would write:

```
$('input[name=search]').focusout( //Close ul  );
```

But how I can detect if the focus is outside the input and ul?

---

I think I found a really simple way.

Here is the function

```
$(body).click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('custom-ul') && $(e.target).attr('name') != 'search')
    { //...do stuff }
});
```

Comment: Can't you use $('ul').focusout(....); ?

Comment: Yes I can use, but If the input lost the focus, the ul will close

Comment: $('input[name=search], ul').focusout(....) ?

Comment: The event.target isn't set at this time, its everytime the body...

Comment: nice solution, but this function will be called a lot of times for nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You can detect focus out from input but not also from unordered list.

or try something like this

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if ( $optionsHolder.data('hidden') || $optionsHolder.is(':animated') ) {
        return;
    }
   $selectedHolder.click();
})
```

[How to trigger focusout event on a ul element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844263/how-to-trigger-focusout-event-on-a-ul-element)

Comment: Nice idea, but I think I found a cleaner way ;)
I add it to my question

Comment: I'm not seeing what is cleaner way which u fix the problem but great anyway :)